# How to make 2 function loop n times with time delay after each run?

Tags: javascript

I have two pairs of functions. These functions need to run 9 times, for 3 seconds (length of time). A delay between each run should be 1 second.

Is there a better way to shorten the loopIT() function?

```js
window.onload = function () {

  // Get the button that will trigger the action
  var b = document.getElementById('trigger');
  // and set the onclick handler here instead of in HTML
  b.onclick = loopIT;

  function startIT() {
    // close switch, turn the light on.
  }
  function stopIT() {
    // open switch, turn the light off.
  }

  function loopIT() {
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #1
    setTimeout(startIT, 100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 3100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #2
    setTimeout(startIT, 4100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 7100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #3
    setTimeout(startIT, 8100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 11100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #4
    setTimeout(startIT, 12100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 15100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #4
    setTimeout(startIT, 16100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 19100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #5
    setTimeout(startIT, 22100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 25100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #6
    setTimeout(startIT, 26100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 29100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #7
    setTimeout(startIT, 30100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 33100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #8
    setTimeout(startIT, 34100);
    setTimeout(stopIT, 37100);
    // Lights on, wait 3 seconds, turn lights off. #9
  }        
}
```

Comment: something like `for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) { setTimeout(startIT, (4000 * i) + 100); setTimeout(stopIT, (4000 * i ) + 3100); }`

Answer (score 0):

You could use two for loops.

```
    function loopIT() {
        // goes from #1 to #4 (inclusive)
        for (var i = 4000; i <= 16000; i += 4000) {
            setTimeout(startIT, i + 100);
            setTimeout(stopIT, i + 3100);
        }
        // goes from #5 to #9 (inclusive)
        for (var j = 22000; j <= 34000; j += 4000) {
            setTimeout(startIT, j + 100);
            setTimeout(stopIT, j + 3100);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval`, which will run a certain function every N milliseconds.

You can use a counter to stop after N times.

```js
// count the number of times we turned the lights on
var cpt = 0;
// turn the lights on right away
lightsOn();
// turn the lights on every 3 seconds
var intervalOn = setInterval(lightsOn, 3000);

function lightsOn()
{
  console.log("lights on");

  // Turn the lights off in 1 second
  setTimeout(lightsOff, 1000);
}

function lightsOff()
{
  console.log("lights off");
  ++cpt;
  
  // If we've turned off the lights 9 times, stop turning the lights on.
  if (cpt == 9)
  {
    clearInterval(intervalOn);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to use a do-while loop that keeps going until you reach the end (in your case about 40s). You can also add an iterator that is increased once per loop.

```
function loopIt() {

  let timeout = 100;

  do {
     setTimeout(startIt(), timeout);
     timeout += 3000;
     setTimeout(stopIt(), timeout);
     timeout += 1000;
  } while (timeout < 40000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is :

```
var repeatedTimes = 0;
function loopIt(){ 
    if(repeatedTimes < 9){
      startIT();
      setTimeout(stopIT, 3000);
      setTimeout(loopIt, 4000);
    }
    repeatedTimes++;
}
setTimeout(loopIt, 100);
```

hope it helps